# define range for non number variables in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
set ln=o

:lap
set/a ln=%ln%+1
set lp%ln%=time%ln%

for %%l in (%lp1%,%lp2%,%lp3%,%lp4%,%lp5%,%lp6%,%lp7%,%lp8%,%lp9%,%lp10%,%lp11%,%lp12%,%lp13%,%lp14%,%lp15%,%lp16%,%lp17%,%lp18%,%lp19%,%lp20%) do echo %%l

pause
goto lap
```

so i need to replace the `(%lp1%,%lp2%,%lp3%,%lp4%,%lp5%,%lp6%,%lp7%,%lp8%,%lp9%,%lp10%,%lp11%,%lp12%,%lp13%,%lp14%,%lp15%,%lp16%,%lp17%,%lp18%,%lp19%,%lp20%)` with something like `[%lp1%-%lp20%]` but as they are not numbers ...

any ideas?

i cant use the for/l bcs each time the loop runs the outputs should increase one by one.

also i tried
`for %%l in (1,1,20) do set a=%lp%%l% & echo %a%`
but that doesnt work

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) for how to make your last code line work.

Comment: But when i use enabledelayedexpansion and run it it returns echo is off for those values of %%l that have not yet been defined as each loop defines a new variable

Comment: Try `for /L %%e in (1,1,%ln%) do CALL echo %%lp%%e%%`

Comment: for the `echo is OFF` issue: `echo/%lp%%l%`

Comment: **The first mistake is that `set ln=o` should be `Set "ln=0"`.** Then `set/a ln=%ln%+1` should be `Set /A ln=ln+1` or better `Set /A ln += 1`. You should also use `Set "lp%ln%=time%ln%"`.